# How to skip empty value in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I have a little script to set displayname in bulk for some user. But some of my users do not have a value like 'Firstname' and 'Lastname' in there objects. I have tried to look for it, but cannot find to skip this users from my script.

```
$UPNs = Import-Csv -Path "C:\temp\users.csv" -Delimiter “;”

#.UserPrincipalName, means the value of the first row in CSV file
$Users = ForEach($UPN in $UPNs){Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UPN.UserPrincipalName | Select-Object Userprincipalname,displayname,firstname,lastname}

$Users | ForEach-Object {
    $DisplayName = $_.firstname + " " + $_.lastname + " " + "(Admin Account)"
    set-msoluser -UserPrincipalName $_.userprincipalname -DisplayName $DisplayName
}
```

How can I made this script to say, "no 'firstname' or 'lastname' -> do not change object"

Many thanks,

Ricardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use the `Where-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/removing-objects-from-the-pipeline--where-object-?view=powershell-7.1):

```
# Filter out users unless both FirstName and LastName has values
$Users |Where-Object {$_.FirstName -and $_.LastName} | ForEach-Object {
    $DisplayName = $_.firstname + " " + $_.lastname + " " + "(Admin Account)"
    set-msoluser -UserPrincipalName $_.userprincipalname -DisplayName $DisplayName
}
```

Here, we use the `-and` boolean logic operator to ensure that both `$_.FirstName` and `$_.LastName` has a value that is *truthy* - `$null` and empty strings will evaluate to `$false` in a boolean context, strings with any other value will evaluate to `$true`.

If you also want to skip when either consists of just whitespace, use the static `[string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` method

```
# Filter out users unless both FirstName and LastName has non-whitespace-only values
$Users |Where-Object {-not([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.FirstName)) -and -not([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.LastName))} | ForEach-Object {
    $DisplayName = $_.firstname + " " + $_.lastname + " " + "(Admin Account)"
    set-msoluser -UserPrincipalName $_.userprincipalname -DisplayName $DisplayName
}
```